# How to log raw POST request from aiohttp client?

Tags: logging, aiohttp

I have a POST request that is working well with `requests`, but is misinterpreted by the server when using aiohttp client. Is there a way to log the raw POST request from aiohttp client to compare them?

For context, this is how I'm using `requests`:

```
url = 'https://www.places4students.com/Places/PropertyListings?SchoolID=FzhtQRDGtSU='

for next_page in range(4):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.request(
        'POST', url,
        data={'__EVENTARGUMENT': f'Page${next_page}'},
        cookies={'Places4StudentDisclaimer': 'Agree'}
    ).content, 'html.parser')
```

Here's the aiohttp client version of the code:

```
async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=connector) as session:
    async with session.request(
        'POST', url,
        data={'__EVENTARGUMENT': f'Page${next_page}'},
        cookies={'Places4StudentDisclaimer': 'Agree'}
    ) as response:
        content = await response.text()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
```